# SQL Server export data from synonyms table to excel

Tags: sql-server, export, excel, synonyms

I tried to export synonyms table from my server database to excel using SMSS, I choose database, then I choose export, and manage source and dest, then I choose Excel File and I rename `sheet 1` to `name of synonyms table`.

The base table that the synonym points to is on another server and another database, but I just handle db server with table synonym, I just want to use the synonym to pull data across the linked server.

when I execute, I got error about `table x don't exist` but I have synonyms :)m and I can choose it from export wizard, anyone know about how to export data from table of synonyms to excel file?

Comment: Have you tried exporting from the base table directly, rather than via the synonym?

Comment: Base table from another server and another database, but I just handle db server with table synonym,  I just want to do it in synonym, have any solution?

Comment: That's a very important detail! I'm not sure how BCP works across a linked server like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use a SQL Query, as synonyms don't show up in the list of tables and views Excel (Power Query) retrieves from the server.  EG

[image]

Comment: I think he's going the other way around and trying to use the SSMS Export Wizard (Database Task) to export the Table to an Excel file.

Comment: it work, it detect the synonyms table by query, maybe, for export data using synonyms, I use power query excel, but takes a long time because I export 5.5 Million row, first I use it, I got timed out, I retry, and run, thanks for you help